# Laravel 5.8 Too few arguments error for jobs

Tags: php, laravel, jobs, laravel-5.8

I'm getting error below in the failed jobs table.

`Too few arguments to function App\Jobs\updateTeamToDoProgress::handle(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected in /var/www/eu_dash_laravel_dev/laravel/app/Jobs/updateTeamToDoProgress.php:32`

I've spent lots of time looking at solutions to the same issue from other folks but can't figure out what's wrong in my code.

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Http\Controllers\ToDoController;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;


class updateTeamToDoProgress implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $tries = 5;
    protected $trip_id;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($trip_id)
    {
        $this->trip_id = $trip_id;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        echo ToDoController::updateTeamToDoProgress($this->trip_id);
    }
}
```

Dispatching using `dispatch(new App\Jobs\updateTeamToDoProgress(172));`

Help? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `$job = new App\Jobs\updateTeamToDoProgress(172); dispatch($job)`

Comment: @BohdanPetrenko . Thanks for the suggestion. But that didn't change anything. I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your job class is correct.

```
    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        echo ToDoController::updateTeamToDoProgress($this->trip_id);
    }
```

You can try to change dispatching syntax in your controller:

instead:

```
dispatch(new YourJobClass(172));
```

try:

```
$this->dispatch(new YourJobClass(172));
```

Comment: Nope, this is not required.

Comment: @Arm092 That didn't change anything. I get the same error.